# Unexpected failure when using XCreateImage with LodePNG

Tags: image, background, window, png, xlib

I am trying to add a background image to a X11 window, in Linux. I use the simple LodePNG to decode the PNG image into raw data (RGBA) then I try to set the window background.
What happens is that the window shows up for a while then it unexpectedly closes back. If I comment out the `XCreateImage` and `XPutImage` function (including the destructors) the window shows up correctly, so the window creation is not a problem.
My code looks like this:

```
// Headers here (xlib, lodepng) ...

// Global vars ...
Display *display;
Window window;
int window_width = 640;
int window_height = 480;

// Entry point, initialization, window creation ...
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    vector<unsigned char> image; //the raw pixels
    unsigned width, height;

    // Decode
    unsigned error = lodepng::decode(image, width, height, "bg.png");

    // If there's no error continue
    if(!error)
    {
        Pixmap pixmap = XCreatePixmap
        (
            display, 
            XDefaultRootWindow(display), 
            width, 
            height, 
            DefaultDepth(display, 0)
        );

        XGCValues gr_values; 
        GC gr_context = XCreateGC
        (
            display, 
            window, 
            GCBackground, 
            &gr_values
        );

        // Here is where it fails !!!
        unsigned rowbytes = 0;
        XImage *ximage = XCreateImage
        (
            display, 
            CopyFromParent, 
            32, 
            XYPixmap, 
            0, 
            (char*)image.data(), 
            width, 
            height, 
            32, 
            rowbytes
        );

        XPutImage(
            display, 
            pixmap, 
            gr_context, 
            ximage, 
            0, 0, 
            0, 0, 
            window_width, 
            window_height
        );

        XSetWindowBackgroundPixmap(display, window, pixmap);

        XFreePixmap(display, pixmap);
        XFreeGC(display, gr_context);
        XDestroyImage(ximage);
    }
}
```

After I decode the PNG I can see that I get the correct width and height of the image. The size of the raw data (`image` variable) is always 819200, no matter what image I choose, which is a bit weird and I wonder if LodePNG is not loading the image correctly (yet it gives no error and correct width and height). Other causes of this problem, I don't know. I don't get any error message, the window just closes after being saw a little bit. Maybe some of the arguments of `XCreateImage` is wrong but I can't figure out which.

Comment: data length should correspond to number of pixels (for rgba32 it's pixels x 4). Also I believe you need to use ZPixmap as pixmap format here.

Comment: The problem now is that the image colors are inversed and the image is not stretched over the window but is repeating on the XY axis.